# After installation, the file system change from ext4 to ext3

Tags: 16.04, ext4, ext3

Install 16.04

[image: install 16.04]

Desktop

[image: desktop]

Laptop

[image: laptop]

I installed 16.04 with default setup and it was ext4 file system in another computer. How to fix it?

Comment: What is that application? Design looks old, maybe it is mistaking the ext4 for an ext3. What is the output of `df -Th /`?

Comment: The app is Ext2Fsd/Ext2Mgr.exe, and the output of `df -Th /` is:`Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p5 ext4   98G  5.0G   88G   6% /`

Comment: So, the filesystem is ext4 and the application you are using was programmed prior to the introduction of ext4

Comment: Please see the third picture~

Comment: When Linux says your FS is ext4 and $random_application thinks otherwise, the question should be raised with the authors/maintainers of $random_application.

Comment: Soga, but I just curious why the same software gets a different state on the laptop and desktop computers.

Comment: Me too, but the answer to that question is with its authors.

Comment: I'm curious too.  After checking the source code, it has ext4 support, but there's no ext4 strings in the manager.  So it seems that the author does not bother to change that.

Answer (score 0):

this is bug in ext2fsd driver in Windows.  I have same issue with dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 and I gave a try to ext2fsd... Same issue sees it ext3 and cant read partition using this program